# Calling UICollectionView.reloadData() freezes the app

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have these views

UICollectionView(1) [that contains]-> a Cell -> UICollectionView(2) -> a Cell -> UICollectionView(3)

when calling reloadData on 3rd UICollectionView ( with most depth ) it will freezes the app.

NOTE: I'm not using auto layout

**EDIT:**

for 3rd ui collection view :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.data.count
  }
  //endregion

  //region cellForItemAt
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let item = self.data[indexPath.item]
    return (self.cv.dequeueReusableCell(
        withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierItem,
        for: indexPath) as! AboutCellItem)
        .setImage(URL(string: item.images?.first?.thumbImageUrl ?? "")!)
        .setTitle(item.aboutTitle ?? "-")

  }
  //endregion

  //region size
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if self.data.count == 1 {
      return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: 70)
    } else if self.data.count == 2 {
      return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width / 2, height: 70)
    } else {
      return CGSize(width: ( self.bounds.width / 2.5 ) - Theme.Paddings.mainHorizontal * 1.5 , height: 70)
    }

  }
  //endregion

  //region space
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return Theme.Paddings.mainHorizontal
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return Theme.Paddings.mainHorizontal
  }
```

**EDIT:**

CPU on device goes up to 97% when calling realodData

**EDIT**

updating data source and not calling reloadData 
and updating views by scrolling out the 3rd cv using 2rd cv and then scrolling it in again will works okay

NOTE: calling reloadData with delay doesn't work either

Comment: Can you please explain more with code

Comment: @shivi_shub first I update my data source variable in last cv then calling reloadData on it. it's a huge code base, should I put a specific part of my code?

Comment: You can post collection view datasource function - cellForitematindexpath

Comment: You might be doing long running or heavy task in the main thread.

Comment: @shivi_shub I updated the post

Comment: @vivekDas I am pretty sure thats not the cause

Comment: @Sahandevs you are returing it one line. return (self.cv.dequeueReusableCell(         withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifierItem,         for: indexPath) as! AboutCellItem)         .setImage(URL(string: item.images?.first?.thumbImageUrl ?? "")!)         .setTitle(item.aboutTitle ?? "-") first set image and title then just return the cell

Comment: @shivi_shub it's a builder like pattern it should be fine ( it returns itself at the end )

Comment: @Sahandevs i know. But try to write separately once

Comment: 1. Use the debugger and see what's happening when it freezes. 2. Do you really need three levels of collection views? There's got to be a better solution.

Comment: You’re dequing a cell from ‘self.cv.dequeueReusableCell’ and it’s unclear from the code which controller is it. Switch it to ‘collectionView’ passed to the function. Or update the question with more info.

Comment: @shivi_shub i tried it ( with different order and event without them ) didn't fixed it

Comment: @rmaddy 1 - by stepping forward ( from cv.reloadData() ) it shows assembly part ( and by stepping more it doesn't end ) 2 - i tried few different methods, this is the best one i came up with

Comment: @dive it's the 3rd one